# Asking detailed and varient of an old(9 years) closed question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

I have come across a problem which was already asked [here](https://superuser.com/questions/141752/your-system-administrator-has-set-policies-to-prevent-this-installation) in a very general way in 2010. That question was closed citing as overly broad, vague, ambiguous etc. Now, I have tried many things on this issue, including the accepted answer for that question which also doesn't work for me. So I would like to ask a new question including all the things that I have tried, in order to pinpoint the cause of the error.

Since editing that question seems like a bad idea(because it is closed, has an accepted answer and around 9 years old), can I ask a new question?

Comment: You can ask a new question but it should be a lot more specific than that old one ...

Comment: If your not the an Administrator on the PC expect to be told the program cannot be installed.  If this is a corporate machine or one connected to an AD domain there won’t be a great deal you can do.  We will need a great deal more than just the error message in a case like this.  Be as specific as possible, and be prepared that if the details indicate there isn’t a solution for a non-Administrator, to be told that (through the appropriate duplicate)

Comment: @Ramhound , i tried using domain administrator account. and you are right the machine is connected to AD.

Comment: @ChiefA - If you are indeed an Administrator we might be able to help.  All depends on the clarity of the question.